# How to show ForeignKey fields in Model Form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

```
# models.py

class modelA(models.Model):
    a = models.CharField()
    b = models.CharField()

class ModelB(models.Model):
    c = models.CharField()
    d = models.ForeignKey(modelA)

# forms.py

class myForm (ModelForm):
    class Meta: 
       model = ModelB
       fields = ('d')
       widgets = { 'd' : TextInput() }
```

I want to show a form which displays `a` and `b` fields as `TextInput`and how to do it?

The above `forms.py` code displays `d` as name but not its fields..

Comment: take care, `fields = ('d')` should be `fields = ('d', )`

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are looking for [inline formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets):

> Inline formsets is a small abstraction layer on top of model formsets.
>   These simplify the case of working with related objects via a foreign
>   key. Suppose you have these two models ...

For your models:

```
from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory
ModelBFormSet = inlineformset_factory(ModelB, ModelA)
BInstance = ModelB.objects.get(a=u'some value')
formset = ModelBFormSet(instance=BInstance)
```

Read "[Using an inline formset in a view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-an-inline-formset-in-a-view)" to learn how to use factory.